# Run-time Error -2147417848 (80010108) appears for big amounts of data to process

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the Excel macro I created. The macro is quite complicated (7 modules with ~2500 lines of code) and it's used to automatically assign pallets to trucks and sort them properly. It works perfectly for 99% cases but when recently it had to assign more than 1200 pallets for one direction it stopped working.

The weird thing is that normally it can process way more than that but only if it is splitting for different directions. Also it crashes not in one place but sometimes when building pallet number 1108 sometimes 1110 etc. Between 1108 and 1111.

Also the crashing is quite weird. Before I turned on the "Break on all errors" It was just exiting the Sub that it was at that time working on, going back to the first one and then processing the rest of the code without executing it (ignoring every variable changes, every If etc.) The only line that was working was the Message Box. Also Excel was unresponsive afterwards.

I am declaring every variable, I have `Option Explicit` on top of every module I am using few Public variables and a lot of Local? (the ones that are across the Module not across the Project).

It is crashing mostly at this line:

```
w2.Cells(r, 4).delete Shift:=xlUp
```

where w2 is set as:

```
Set w2 = Workbooks(wb1).Worksheets("SDP Temp")
```

Have you ever encountered something like this?

Comment: Yes. I'm not deleting any sheets etc. I'm only deleting rows from that sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a fix for the problem.

When the code was executing he was never truly exiting the SUBs until the directory was finished. 
Because of that when there was more than 28 trucks it had around 50 subs opened in the background.

When I fixed the code so the subs were properly closed after they were used it started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
0x80010108  RPC_E_DISCONNECTED  The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
```

Is what it means. COM uses RPC for out of process.